# Утечка памяти, язык си

Tags: c

Преподаватель сказал, что происходит утечка памяти в функции, которая начинается на 80 строке. Проблема в пустом векторе, но как исправить плохо понимаю

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>


int def_i = 0;
float def_f = 0;

typedef struct vector { 
   void* buffer;  
   int count;
   int elem_size;
   int flag;  // 0 - int, 1 - float 
}vector;


void set_elem_f(vector* a, int index, void* value) {
  void* p = (char*)a->buffer + a->elem_size * index; 
   memcpy(p, value, a->elem_size); // memcpy() is used to copy a block of memory from a location to another. 
}


void set_elem_i(vector* a, int index, void* value) {
 void* p = (char*)a->buffer + a->elem_size * index;
   memcpy(p, value, a->elem_size);
}


vector* create_int(int count, int elem_size) {
   vector* vec = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(vector));
   vec->count = count;
   vec->elem_size = elem_size;
   vec->buffer = malloc(count * elem_size);
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       set_elem_i(vec, i, &def_i);
   vec->flag = 0;

   return vec;
}

vector* create_float(int count, int elem_size) {
   vector* vec = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(vector));
   vec->count = count;
   vec->elem_size = elem_size;
   vec->buffer = malloc(count * elem_size);
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       set_elem_f(vec, i, &def_f);
   vec->flag = 1;

   return vec;
}

int get_elem_i(vector* a, int index) {
   int* value = (int*)malloc(a->elem_size);
   void* p = (char*)a->buffer + a->elem_size * index;
   memcpy(value, p, a->elem_size);

   int res = *value;
   free(value);
   return res; 
}

float get_elem_f(vector* a, int index) {
   float* value = (float*)malloc(a->elem_size);
   void* p = (char*)a->buffer + a->elem_size * index;
   memcpy(value, p, a->elem_size);

   float res = *value;
   free(value);
   return res;
}




vector* summ_vec(vector* vec1, vector* vec2) {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   if (vec1->count != vec2->count) {
       vector* vec3 = create_float(0, 4);
       printf("Размеры векторов не совпадают.");
   }
   else {

       void* buffer1 = vec1->buffer;
       void* buffer2 = vec2->buffer;
       int count = vec1->count;
       vector* vec3 = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(vector));
       vec3->elem_size = 4;
       vec3->count = count;

       if ((vec1->flag == 0) && (vec2->flag == 0)) {
           void* buffer3 = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
           vec3->buffer = buffer3;
           int a, b, c;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               a = get_elem_i(vec1, i);
               b = get_elem_i(vec2, i);
               c = a + b;
               set_elem_i(vec3, i, &c);
           }
           vec3->flag = 0;
       }

       if ((vec1->flag == 0) && (vec2->flag == 1)) {
           void* buffer3 = (float*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
           vec3->buffer = buffer3;
           int a;
           float c, b;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               a = get_elem_i(vec1, i);
               b = get_elem_f(vec2, i);
               c = (float)a + b;
               set_elem_f(vec3, i, &c);
           }
           vec3->flag = 1;
       }

       if ((vec1->flag == 1) && (vec2->flag == 0)) {
           void* buffer3 = (float*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
           vec3->buffer = buffer3;
           int b;
           float a, c;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               a = get_elem_f(vec1, i);
               b = get_elem_i(vec2, i);
               c = a + (float)b;
               set_elem_f(vec3, i, &c);
           }
           vec3->flag = 1;
       }

       if ((vec1->flag == 1) && (vec2->flag == 1)) {
           void* buffer3 = (float*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
           vec3->buffer = buffer3;
           float a, b;
           float c;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               a = get_elem_f(vec1, i);
               b = get_elem_f(vec2, i);
               c = a + b;
               set_elem_f(vec3, i, &c);
           }
           vec3->flag = 1;

       }

       return vec3;
   }
}
```

введите сюда код

Comment: Я конечно не Сишник, но может надо делать: free (buffer3)

Comment: Да, обязать вызывающего функцию summ_vec освобождать саму переменную что ему вернули можно. Но объяснять ему, что внутри есть указатель на буфер, который то же надо освобождать - проблематично (тем более реализация может меняться). Лучше бы сделать vector классом, который сам заботиться о своей памяти, в том числе освобождает буфер в деструкторе. Хотя конечно тут нет кода, вызывающего  summ так что ситуация не определенная. Ну или сделать функцию free_vec и обязать вызывающего summ использовать потом ее (что написать скажем в комментах перед summ :) )

Answer (score 0):

строка 80:

Переменную результата объявите одну, внутри условий не надо и возвращать нужно результат всегда. Утечка памяти была при ошибке разных размеров. Создаёте новый вектор и его **не** возвращаете.

```
vector* summ_vec(vector* vec1, vector* vec2) {
    vector * vec3 = NULL ;
    ...
    return vec3 ; }
```

строка 82:

```
if (vec1->count != vec2->count) {
       //vector* vec3 = create_float(0, 4);
```

При ошибке вы возвращаете вектор ненужный. Можно просто вернуть **NULL** с инструкций, что функция может это вернуть.

строка 96:

```
void* buffer3 = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
```

строка 105:

```
vec3->flag = 0;
```

Тип вектора **int**, а память выделяете под **float**. Исправить нужно на `sizeof(int)`.

Деструктор вы не написали. Примерно такой:

```
void vector_destr(vector * const v) {
  if(v)
      free(v->buffer); }

void vector_delete(vector * const v) {
  vector_destr(v);
  free(v); }
```

Каждый раз, при освобождении вектора, нужно его вызывать :

```
vector * const tmp = summ_vec ( vec1 , vec2 ) ;
...
vector_delete(tmp);
```